# Proper way to calculate time for pattern algorithm read from file with buffer

Tags: c++, pattern-matching

I have a problem in gathering data for Pattern Finding Algorithms.

Measurement Algorithm:

```
double PCFreq = 0.0;
__int64 CounterStart = 0;

void StartCounter()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    if(!QueryPerformanceFrequency(&li))
        cout << "QueryPerformanceFrequency failed!\n";

    PCFreq = double(li.QuadPart)/1000.0;

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
    CounterStart = li.QuadPart;
}
double GetCounter()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
    return double(li.QuadPart-CounterStart)/PCFreq;
}
```

In each iteration of for I am increasing number of characters in pattern.
In each iteration of while I am reading 2048 characters in a buffer from file that is 500000 random characters from alphabet and then I use pattern finding algorithm on it.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {

    cout << pat << endl;
    file_1 = fopen("alphabet_1.txt", "a+");
    file_2 = fopen("alphabet_2.txt", "a+");
    file_3 = fopen("alphabet_3.txt", "a+");

    StartCounter();
    while (!feof(file_1)) {
        const size_t nchars = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer) - 1, file_1);
        buffer[nchars] = '\0';
        BM(buffer, pat);
    }
    time1 = GetCounter();
    cout << time1 << endl;

    StartCounter();
    while (!feof(file_2)) {
        const size_t nchars = fr

        StartCounter();
        while (!feof(file_3)) {
            const size_t nchars = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer) - 1, file_3);
            buffer[nchars] = '\0';
            SUNDAY(buffer, pat_a);
        }
        time3 = GetCounter();
        cout << time3 << endl;

        size_of = pat.size();
        abc_pat << left << setw(15) << size_of << left << setw(15) << time1 << left << setw(15) << time2 << left << setw(15) << time3 << endl;
        pat += random_PAT(2);
        cout << pat << endl;
    }
}
```

Here's the data gathered but it doesn't seem to be right:

```
Pattern Size         Boyer          KMP            Sunday
     1              7.29172        4.09554        5.29126   
     4              3.42968        4.03492        4.81207   
     7              2.32056        4.24628        4.7306    
     10             2.25833        4.26425        4.89514   
     13             1.56521        4.38645        4.63406   
     16             1.80224        4.21196        4.69468   
     19             1.65085        4.25847        4.97276   
     22             1.40548        3.97077        4.62123   
     25             1.52448        4.11863        4.77454   
     28             1.81347        4.38837        4.77743   
     31             2.02291        4.06378        4.91791   
     34             1.75894        4.26457        4.84318   
     37             1.59119        4.27419        4.74985   
     40             1.62615        4.24853        4.60231   
     43             1.65149        4.20202        4.86948   
     46             1.76664        4.0965         4.84671   
     49             1.47316        4.34154        4.92882   
     52             1.41511        4.44226        4.91374   
     55             1.33011        4.42333        4.79796   
     58             1.42569        4.06956        4.48459   
     61             1.4536         4.12536        4.87269
```

Pattern finding codes are not mine, I collected them here to gather data.
When I tested them, they worked properly, returned the same amount of pattern found etc.

Comment: What do your results mean and why do you think they are incorrect?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Results are time/tics/? needed to complete the function (Sunday, KMP, BM pattern algorithms) with set number of pattern. They are incorrect because I compared it with my friend's results.  I am getting better results by having functions outside `while` buffer. Example StartCounter();    BM(buffer, pat); GetCounter(); Maybe this reading buffer method is not correct?

Comment: What are your friend's results? how do you know theirs are correct? what do you mean by "I am getting better results by having functions outside while buffer"?